# LINQ where condition with string operations

Tags: linq

I get this **error** when that linq code runs. I try many string methods like concat,join,etc. But LINQ doesn't permit string operations.  Finally error is runtime error.

**ERROR**: System.NotSupportedException: 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)'

```
public List<ItemEntity> GetItems(List<string> codeList)
{
    return ExecuteCrud(session =>
    {
        return (from Item in session.Query<ItemEntity>()
                where (codeList.Contains(Item.code) || codeList.Contains($"{Item.Id.ToString().PadLeft(10, '0')}-{ Item.ItemId.ToString().PadLeft(12, '0')}"))
                select Item).ToList();
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is `shipmentItem` coming from? Is that meant to be `Item`?

Comment: `shipmentItem` seems to be defined outside of the Linq conditions -- if that's true, you could probably create a variable beforehand where you store the `$"{  }"` expression and use that directly in the `Contains()` statement?

Comment: You can not cast or something like that concat in query. You have to do it  beginning of return scope. We don't know about shipment Item. Is it changing dynamically ? if it is, you must check null

Comment: shipmenItem miss-written. sorry. I fix it.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider? You can replace the formatting with concatenation but I am not sure `PadLeft` is supported depending on which LINQ...

Comment: LINQ to objects. Database is MSSQL. I also removed 'PadLeft' and nothing changed.